# NodeJS stack executing

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, websocket, socket.io

I have one big problem in my application, but first i will describe by specifications:

Frontend:

- JS + Socket.io

Backend:
   - Nodejs with code in coffeescript
   - Express framework

The app is work in this way:

1. I have this:

   ```
   io = require('socket.io')(server);
   io.sockets.on 'connection', (socket) ->
       socket.on "start:upload", (options)->
           VkSdk = new require './controllers/VkSdk'
           VkSdk.initUpload options
   ```
2. I call some recursive functions.

   ```
   @initUpload: (options) ->
     Product.allByCollection Object.keys(options.collection), (collection) ->
     uploader = require '../lib/uploader'
     uploader.init options
   ```
3. Export part of module uploader

   ```
   exports.init = (options) ->
     uploader = new Uploader();
     uploader.upload()
   ```
4. Execute method class

   ```
   class Uploader
     vksdk      : new require './vk'
     urls       : []

     upload: =>
       @vksdk.getUploadUrl()
       .on '1:done', (data) =>
         @urls.push data
         do @upload
   ```

   5. The getGetUploadUrl method:

      ```
      @getUploadUrl = ->
        url = "urlLink"
        @bus = new events.EventEmitter()

        request
          uri: url
        , (err, res, data) =>
          @bus.emit '1:done', data

        @bus
      ```

The problem is: 
For One user it is work fine. But if i try to trigger one event from front-end to backend, the execution of function of first user trigger is stoped without the errors or notification.

Comment: Sounds like you might be using a global variable to store some state, which gets overwritten by the second request. Difficult to say without some actual code, though.

Comment: Its pretty hard to tell from the code provided. It seems unlikely the issue is in the provided code. Though it could be related to this https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_asynchronous_vs_synchronous. You should be doing something asynchronous inside of the event handle so that you do not block other handlers of an event. The easy way is to just add a `setImmediate -> ` before your code.